# How to group up filter values in sharepoint search rest api?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, rest

In sharepoint 2013 search rest api, I have a more complex query filter, that I would want to group by brackets with `and` and `or` operators. How can this be done?

I have something like

```
field1:A OR (field1:B AND field2:C)
```

how can I do something like this in the `querytext` parameter?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it? using the url `?$filter=Field1 eq 'A' OR (Field1 eq 'B' AND Field2 eq 'C')`

Comment: That's for when u query the list directly, but for search rest, isn't it using the way I have?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found this:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394606.aspx and it suggests you should be using FQL, using and() and or(). So the query text should be something like: `query?querytext='or(field1:equals('A'), and(field1:equals('B'), field2:equals('C'))`

Comment: Also, use this tool to figure out your querytext: http://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

something on the lines of:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&refinementfilters='OR(field1:A,AND("*",field1:B,field2:C))'
```

you need to have fql tho.